# Recommended DAW apps for tablets

Tags: daw, app, mobile, smartphone

I am looking for a DAW that can go on a mobile tablet device.

I am aware that there are many on the available but all the ones I've tried (FL Mobile and GarageBand for IOS) feel very much like a significant compromise.

Which DAW app would you recommend?

I haven't bought the tablet yet so it doesn't matter what the software runs on, and I could install Linux on it if that opens up for a decent DAW.

Comment: Hi! "Mobile" usually means smartphone or tablet. Are Laptops out of the question? What about convertibles (detachable keyboard)? Does it have to be a touchscreen? Does it have to be Linux? Do you need software or hardware recommendations or both? Do you have a budget? What DAW are you familiar with yet? Please provide as much info as possible and edit/clarify your question. Thanks!

Comment: What are your current preferences when working on a stationary or a laptop?

Comment: Was thinking about a android/linux tablet. I already have a laptop so kind of feel it's pointless to get a cheaper one and my current one is too expensive to take. I would probably by an extenarl mouse/keyboard. I currently use Logic mainly, but have used Ableton/Fl in the past. budget is somewhat undecided but not more than £350. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some options:

**Get a Windows tablet**

You can keep using the tools you know if your projects are simple enough for the hardware within your budget.

Both [Ableton Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/help/article/number-of-installations/) and [FL Studio](https://support.image-line.com/knowledgebase/base.php?ans=72) licenses permit installing on multiple (2 for Ableton) devices, even cross-platform.

It looks like currently a £300 Lenovo Yoga 2 11.6 2.16 GHz, 4 GB RAM, 500 GB HDD convertible model with touchscreen (B00LJOTI4A) is within your budget and meets the minimum requirements for both [Ableton Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/help/article/requirements-live-9/) and [FL Studio](https://support.image-line.com/knowledgebase/base.php?ans=82).

**Install Linux on a tablet**

[LinuxOnAndroid](http://linuxonandroid.org/downloads/) seems to exist for this purpose. If you succeed, it would be great if you could share your story at the [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218111/installing-linux-on-a-tablet).

What DAW would you use though? There is a [list on Linuxaudio](http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/daw_apps). There is also [Renoise](http://www.renoise.com/), which has a tracker approach to DAW though. I think the one most comparable to FL Studio would be [LMMS](https://lmms.io/), which also runs on OS X and Windows, so you can check now whether it meets your needs. Be warned, that Windows VSTs will not run or perform very badly (with wine) on Linux (no idea about OS X VSTs).

**Embrace the limitations**

Try further apps for tablets:

- Audio Evolution Mobile Studio ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.aemobile&hl=en)), Caustic ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.singlecellsoftware.caustic), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caustic/id775735447?mt=8)) and Cubasis ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/cubasis/id583976519?mt=8)) might be considered compromises.
- SunVox ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nightradio.sunvox&hl=en), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sunvox/id324462544?mt=8)) appears to innovate for touchscreen input

In a way, compromise is unavoidable though.

Tablet apps are focused on touchscreen input and thus make compromises, compared to the precision of the mouse and the resulting permissiveness for small interface objects.

Tablets have mostly low hardware specs compared to audio workstations, which means that they can't support the processor- and memory-intensive features that a complex desktop DAW utilizes.

Comment: Good answer. I think I'll look into the linux option bit more. I've actually used LMMS in the past and quite liked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Nexus(Android OS) that I use when I'm out and about. I tried a few DAW apps, but the one I really liked and stuck with is **Caustic**.

It's well worth the price, and it's quite customizable for an app. There are limitations, as expected, like the reverb unit is not too good and the arranger could be more precise when customizing automation. But there are a lot of positives, Like the modular synth which provides a lot of routing possibilities within it. If you know how to use synths and DAW software, it will be very familiar and easy to use.

Overall I'd say its the best DAW app for Android at the moment.